# How to access mysql database connection of other system in local network in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, networking, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I want to give my junior access of mysql database i have in my system with ubuntu.We are working on one system but need to use one common database.When i add mysql connection of my system in network in cakephp application , it says

**> The page isn’t redirecting properly**

Comment: Did you specify the port ?

Comment: Is you database listening on your external interface?

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin, use like http://remote_ip/phpmyadmin

Comment: Which port i should use can you give example?  kenfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change MySQL configuration file as below.

find my.conf file

in ubuntu ii is located in /etc/mysql
use any file editor to change the file like VIM,namo,gedit...etc
i use nano editor, example given below

> cd /etc/mysql
>   sudo nano my.cnf

Find [mysqld] and add new line under this configration as below , if already exist change it.

bind-address            = XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX is your local machine ip address)

use bind-address            = 0.0.0.0 for any host to use for.

after changing restart MySQL

> sudo service restart mysql

Now you need to create user and grant all permission to connect remotely.

> mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

If you are using phpMyAdmin the you can create user from it.

Now you are ready to connect remotely.